piping from borg into docker container
Hej,
i am having a hard time to get this running. Read all the other answers but some how my case does not fit.
I am doing a pg_dump backup from a container into a borg repo:
docker exec container bash -c "pg_dump -Fc -U db user" | borg create --compression auto,lzma,7 /path/to/repo::pgarchiv -

That is working. I want to restore like this
borg extract --stdout /path/to/repo::pgarchiv | docker exec -i container pg_restore --list

pg_restore is returning the toc (nice) but in the end borg complains about a broken pipe:
Local Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "borg/archiver.py", line 5168, in main
  File "borg/archiver.py", line 5099, in run
  File "borg/archiver.py", line 183, in wrapper
  File "borg/archiver.py", line 198, in wrapper
  File "borg/archiver.py", line 917, in do_extract
  File "borg/archive.py", line 781, in extract_item
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

So there is still something wrong I don't know what. Maybe you do?

You shouldn't need docker exec to run the PostgreSQL admin tools.  Can you install pg_dump and pg_restore on your host system, and connect them to a published port of your database container?

@DavidMaze For security reasons ports of our DBs are not published. They just work inside docker network.
